# Directional shadow mapping in deferred shading

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow, opengl-3, deferred-rendering

I'm implementing directional shadow mapping in deferred shading.

First, I render a depth map from light view (orthogonal projection).

Result:
 [image: result]

I intend to do VSM so above buffer is R32G32 storing depth and depth * depth.

Then for a full-screen shading pass for shadow (after a lighting pass), I write the following pixel shader:

```
    #version 330

    in vec2 texCoord; // screen coordinate
    out vec3 fragColor; // output color on the screen

    uniform mat4 lightViewProjMat; // lightView * lightProjection (ortho)

    uniform sampler2D sceneTexture; // lit scene with one directional light
    uniform sampler2D shadowMapTexture;
    uniform sampler2D scenePosTexture; // store fragment's 3D position

    void main() {
      vec3 fragPos = texture(scenePosTexture, texCoord).xyz; // get 3D position of pixel
      vec4 fragPosLightSpace = lightViewProjMat * vec4(fragPos, 1.0); // project it to light-space view: lightView * lightProjection

      // projective texture mapping
      vec3 coord = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
      coord = coord * 0.5 + 0.5;

      float lightViewDepth; // depth value in the depth buffer - the maximum depth that light can see
      float currentDepth; // depth of screen pixel, maybe not visible to the light, that's how shadow mapping works
      vec2 moments; // depth and depth * depth for later variance shadow mapping

      moments = texture(shadowMapTexture, coord.xy).xy;
      lightViewDepth = moments.x;
      currentDepth = fragPosLightSpace.z;

      float lit_factor = 0;
      if (currentDepth <= lightViewDepth)
        lit_factor = 1; // pixel is visible to the light
      else
        lit_factor = 0; // the light doesn't see this pixel

      // I don't do VSM yet, just want to see black or full-color pixels
      fragColor = texture(sceneTexture, texCoord).rgb * lit_factor;
}
```

The rendered result is a black screen, but if I hard coded the lit_factor to be 1, result is:

[image: result]

Basically that's how the sceneTexture looks like.

So I think either my depth value is wrong, which is unlikely, or my projection (light space projection in above shader / projective texture mapping) is wrong. Could you validate it for me?

My shadow map generation code is:

```
// vertex shader
#version 330 compatibility

uniform mat4 lightViewMat; // lightView
uniform mat4 lightViewProjMat; // lightView * lightProj

in vec3 in_vertex;
out float depth;

void main() {
  vec4 vert = vec4(in_vertex, 1.0);
  depth = (lightViewMat * vert).z / (500 * 0.2); // 500 is far value, this line tunes the depth precision
  gl_Position = lightViewProjMat * vert;
}

// pixel shader
#version 330

in float depth;
out vec2 out_depth;

void main() {
  out_depth = vec2(depth, depth * depth);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the depth you store in the shadow map:

```
depth = (lightViewMat * vert).z / (500 * 0.2);
```

This is the depth you compare the read back value to:

```
vec4 fragPosLightSpace = lightViewProjMat * vec4(fragPos, 1.0);
currentDepth = fragPosLightSpace.z;
```

If `fragPos` is in world space then I assume `lightViewMat * vert == fragPos`. You are compressing depth by dividing by `500 * 0.2`, but that does not equal to `fragPosLightSpace.z`.

Hint: Write out the value of currentDepth in one channel and the value from the shadow map in another channel, you can then compare them visually or in RenderDoc or similar.

Comment: Thank you, it really fixes my problem, plus I discovered that I bound the false texture so scenePosTexture was useless. Some initial shadow: https://i.imgur.com/lTqkMkB.png I need to correct this more.

Answer (score 1):

The `z` component of the fragment shader built in variable [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) contains the depth value in range [0.0, 1.0]. This is the value which you shoud store to the depth map:

```
out_depth = vec2(gl_FragCoord.z, depth * depth);
```

After the calculation

```
vec3 fragPos = texture(scenePosTexture, texCoord).xyz; // get 3D position of pixel
vec4 fragPosLightSpace = lightViewProjMat * vec4(fragPos, 1.0); // project it to light-space view: lightView * lightProjection
vec3 ndc_coord = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
```

the variable `ndc_coord` contains a normalized device coordinate, where all components are in range [-1.0, 1.0].

The `z` component of the normalized device coordiante can be conveted to the depth value (if the [depth range](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml) is [0.0, 1.0]), by

```
float currentDepth = ndc_coord.z * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

This value can be compared to the value from the depth map, because `currentDepth` and `lightViewDepth` are calcualted by the same view matrix and projection matrix:

```
moments = texture(shadowMapTexture, coord.xy).xy;
lightViewDepth = moments.x;

if (currentDepth <= lightViewDepth)
    lit_factor = 1; // pixel is visible to the light
else
    lit_factor = 0; // the light doesn't see this pixel
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I met another problem here but using your suggestion helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507646